# How to create an async callback in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, callback

I'm trying to add an async callback to a model in a flutter application so the model can give the view an opportunity to show some dialog before the model continues on. However, I can't seem to find an async callback. I see `VoidedCallback` but I don't see anything like `Callback<Future>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `VoidCallback` is just a signature for method callback without parameters.

```
typedef VoidCallback = void Function();
```

You can create your own:

```
typedef FutureCallback = void Function(Future);
```

Or you can just use the `final Function(Function) foo = yourcallback` directly.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me: `typedef FutureCallback = Future Function();`

Comment: can you tell in details how to use the solution ?

Comment: I think in the above mentioned example, the async version of `VoidCallback` should be `typedef FutureCallback = Future<void> Function();`, not `void Function(Future)`.

Answer (score 17):

Flutter has an async version of the `VoidCallback` `typedef`, namely `AsyncCallback`. See: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/AsyncCallback.html

Answer (score 2):

This is how you define an async callback function in Dart:

```
typedef FutureCallback = Future<void> Function();
```

Example:

```
FutureCallback myFunction;

await myfunction.call();
```